# Symfony Web Debug Toolbar in External App

Tags: symfony

How can I inject Symfony Web Debug Toolbar in an external app?

I use Symfony just for backend it does not deliver any Html/JS content, but I would like to see the Web Debug Toolbar in the app and access the request from it.

I am currently using Symfony 5.1